# Java concurrency - How to synchronize on method parameter

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency, parallel-processing, synchronization

I have a question related to synchronization and concurrency in Java.

So I have a method, like this:

```
private boolean loadData(final Integer fundId, List<Trade> trades) {
        synchronized (fundId) {
            // do lots of things here and finally load the trades into DB
        }
    }
```

Before I made this change, the complete method `loadData` was synchronized `private synchronized boolean loadData`. However, my requirement is such that if, lets say, fundId - 1 is processing, then I can allow concurrent processing of any other fundId other than 1.

So, the above code also won't work because the lock would be on the Integer object, hence no other fundId can be concurrently processed.
Is there a way to achieve concurrent processing based on the method parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an entry in a `ConcurrentHashMap` for each value of fundId in order to lock it.

```
   static Map<Integer, Object> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
   private boolean loadData(final Integer fundId, List<Trade> trades){
        locks.computeIfAbsent(fundId, k-> { /* your actual job */ return null; });
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: The objects inside the `locks` are never deleted, which may consume the entire memory in a long running process.

Comment: Please have a look at my comment. "Don't forget to release the fundId locked once you terminate processing". Releasing the lock means deleting the entry and hence no object in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the help,this is very similar to what @k1r0 suggested. Will try it out and update you guys after that :-)
Thanks for the help once again.

Comment: How is this different from `synchronized (fundId)`? What problem with that does it solve?

Comment: Thanks @Holger for the comment. It was indeed very helpful and Thanks M.Mas for the update to the answer

Answer (score 1):

The function, as it is written, will synchronize on the object `fundId`, not on `Integer`. So, it will block if you call the same function from another thread with the same `fundId` instance. It will not, however, synchronize if you call it with other `fundId` instances, regardless of the value.

If you need to synchronize based on a value, you can use a shared set of integers (i.e. fundId). Synchronize on the set, and attempt to insert the integer. If it is already in there, someone else is processing that value, so you wait. If it is not there, then you insert it, unlock, process, lock again, remove the value, and signal.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that in several ways:

- If the class that contains `loadData()` is called `FundLoader` you can have a `Map<Integer, FundLoader> fundLoaders` and each FundLoader is responsible to load the trades for given fundId. The synchronization will be again on method level for `loadData`
- Do a custom synhronization inside loadData
  **UPDATE - added fundsWaitingForLock to prevent cases when the lock is already taken from the fundLocks map**

```
private final Map<Integer, Object> fundLocks = new HashMap<>();
private final Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> fundsWaitingForLock = new HashMap<>();

private boolean loadData(final Integer fundId, final List<String> trades) {
    Object lock;
    synchronized (fundLocks) {
        lock = fundLocks.computeIfAbsent(fundId, id -> new Object());
        fundsWaitingForLock.computeIfAbsent(fundId, id -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
    }
    synchronized(lock) {
        try {
            // do lots of things here and finally load the trades into DB
            return true;
        } finally {
            synchronized (fundLocks) {
                if (fundsWaitingForLock.get(fundId).decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                    fundLocks.remove(fundId);
                    fundsWaitingForLock.remove(fundId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Pass a lock instead of fundId.

```
private boolean loadData(final Lock fundIdLock, final List<String> trades) {
    fundIdLock.lock();
    try {
        // do lots of things here and finally load the trades into DB
    } finally {
        fundIdLock.unlock();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you the first and second ideas seem to be very good. I can try those out.

Comment: How is this different from `synchronized (fundId)`? What problem with that does it solve?

Comment: This is subject to the same race condition as the `ConcurrentHashMap` variant, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544893/java-concurrency-how-to-synchronize-on-method-parameter#comment110618549_62545166). `computeIfAbsent` will return the already contained object if there is one, so the first thread’s `remove(fundId)` can remove an object already in use by a second (or an arbitrary number of threads).

Comment: True, I added a counter for the number of threads waiting for the lock and the remove is done only if it reaches 0.